# Outputting the results of a rollback stored proc in a C# Gridview before committing

Tags: c#, sql, gridview, stored-procedures

I have two stored procedures which are exactly the same, the only difference being one commits the inserts/updates, whilst the other runs in rollback mode.

**What I am trying to achieve.**

I want the user to fill out the 3 variables and then click a button, this button should then set up and execute the `ROLLBACK` version of the stored procedure. The user will then be presented with an OK/Cancel dialog MessageBox. If the data looks okay the user will then select OK from the `DialogResult`, if not they select Cancel. If they do select OK this is when the `COMMIT` version of the stored procedure will execute.

**My problem.**

Currently in the code I have copied what I have done for the commit version of the stored proc. i.e once the changes have been mad the dataset is refreshed and the gridview updated. As the `ROLLBACK` version of the stored proc will not actually make any changes the gridview is never going to show the user what the data WILL look like if they click OK.

In SSMS, if I exec the rollback stored proc it will display a select statement before the `ROLLBACK TRAN` part, which essentially shows me what the data will look like. Its this `SELECT` statement that I want to update my dataset with so that the user can inspect the changes before clicking OK (commit)

**My Question**

Is there anyway of using the `SELECT` statement within the rollback stored proc to update my dataset/gridview, if not is there anyway of changing my `SQLDataAdapter` to update the gridview with how the data looks within the transaction of the rollback stored proc, I think I may need to use `ExecuteReader` but I'm not sure where this will fit into my current code.

**Code**

```
//Only execute the updated if there is an ID, OldProfileClass and NewProfileClass specified
                    if (recordID.Text != "" && oldProfileClass.Text != "" && newProfileClass.Text != "")
                    {
                        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(recordID.Text);
                        int oldPC = Convert.ToInt32(oldProfileClass.Text);
                        int NewPC = Convert.ToInt32(newProfileClass.Text);

                        string connstrroll = @"Initial Catalog=mytestdb;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
                        SqlConnection connroll = new SqlConnection(connstrroll);
                        connroll.Open();

                        var cmdroll = new SqlCommand("dbo.myrollbacksp", connroll);
                        cmdroll.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        cmdroll.Parameters.AddWithValue("@meter_id", ID);
                        cmdroll.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new_profile_num", NewPC);
                        cmdroll.Parameters.AddWithValue("@old_profile_num", oldPC);

                        //execute the command 'cmd', the profile class will now be updated at db level
                        cmdroll.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        int numberOfRecordsroll = cmdroll.ExecuteNonQuery();


                        //Once the Profile Class change has been committed, show the results in the gridview
                        using (SqlDataAdapter aroll = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT cust_ref, (region+meter_num_1+meter_num_2) as Number, meter_id, site_name, profile_num FROM dbo.Meter WHERE meter_id = @filter", conn))
                        {
                            int filter = ID;
                            aroll.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filter", filter);
                            // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
                            DataTable t = new DataTable();
                            aroll.Fill(t);

                            // Render data onto the screen
                            gridSelectID.DataSource = t;
                        }

                        //close connections
                        cmdroll.Dispose();
                        connroll.Close();
                        connroll.Dispose();

                        //confirm update
                        MessageBox.Show("Number of records affected:" + numberOfRecordsroll + " Please check the data is correct before proceeding", "Please validate your changes", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);

                        if (DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                            // CODE TO FIRE THE COMMIT VERSION OF STORED PROC GOES HERE
                        }

                        else if (DialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
                        {
                            //DONT RUN THE COMMIT VERSION OF THE STORED PROC
                        }

                        //empty the values of the three text box's once the profile class is updated
                        recordID.Text = "";
                        oldProfileClass.Text = "";
                        newProfileClass.Text = "";
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please provide details for all 3 boxes", "Warning");
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the job...

```
 //show the 'temporary' results in the gridview, taken from the rollback stored proc
                        using (SqlDataAdapter aroll = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdroll))
                        {
                            // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
                            DataTable troll = new DataTable();
                            aroll.Fill(troll);

                            // Render data onto the screen
                            gridSelectID.DataSource = troll;
                        }
```